# How to Crawl Over a Single Website using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup, web-crawler

I am starting of from a websites homepage. I am parsing the entire web page and I am collecting all the links on that homepage and putting them in a queue. Then I am removing each link from the queue and doing the same thing until I get the text that I want. However if I get a link like youtube.com/something then I am going to all the links on youtube. I want to restrict this.

I want to crawl within the same domain only. How do I do that?

```
private void crawler() throws IOException {
    while (!q.isEmpty()){
        String link  = q.remove();
        System.out.println("------"+link);
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).ignoreContentType(true).timeout(0).get();
        if(doc.text().contains("publicly intoxicated behavior or persistence")){
            System.out.println("************ On this page ******************");
            System.out.println(doc.text());
            return;
        }
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link1 : links){ 
            String absUrl = link1.attr("abs:href");
            if (absUrl == null || absUrl.length() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
//          System.out.println(absUrl);
            q.add(absUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-using-java/) shows how to write a web crawler.  The following line forces all crawled links to be on the `mit.edu` domain.

`if(link.attr("href").contains("mit.edu"))`

There might be a bug with that line since relative URLs won't have the domain.  I suggest that adding `abs:` might be better.

`if(link.attr("abs:href").contains("mit.edu"))`